# error while loading shared libraries: __vdso_time: invalid mode for dlopen(): Invalid argument

Tags: linux

Code:

```
wget ftp.gnu.org/gnu/glibc/glibc-2.17.tar.gz
tar zxvf glibc-2.17.tar.gz
cd glibc-2.17
cd ..
mkdir build
cd build
../configure --prefix=/opt/glibc-2.17
make 
make install
```

But after installing glibc-2.17 from source in a separate directory `/opt/glibc-2.17`
and finally after:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/glibc-2.17/lib
```

or:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/glibc-2.17/lib:/opt/glibc-2.17/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so2
```

any software run leads to this error:

> error while loading shared libraries: __vdso_time: invalid mode for
>   dlopen(): Invalid argument

Comment: Please follow SO guideline for posting questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Add more details - what are you installing, your system parameters etc.

Answer (score -1):

You can issue the following command to fix the problems with running commands.

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
```